# Canvas does not appear

Tags: java, swing, awt

For a Java project at school I have to create a simple racing game. I created several classes : one class Vehicle, one class `JDessin` which is a `Canvas`, one class `JeuKarting` which corresponds to the frame. There are a few problems with my code:

- I added a `KeyListener` to make the vehicle move or rotate when in press the arrow buttons, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.
- I added a`Graphics2D` transform in order to make my vehicle rotate when I press left or right arrow but since none of the canvas is drawn on the screen.

Here is my code:

```
\\JDessin class corresponding to the Canvas
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JDessin extends JPanelAnime implements KeyListener {
  static final int T_CANVAS = 500;      // taille du Canvas en pixels (carrÃ©)   
  static final int D_INFLUENCE = 25;    
  static final int D_MIN_DU_BORD = 30;  
  Piste piste; // la piste
  Vehicule vehicule;// le vehicule


  public JDessin(int d) {
    super(d); 
    try {
       // appel du constructeur de la classe mÃ¨re 
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension(T_CANVAS, T_CANVAS));
    vehicule = new Vehicule (T_CANVAS - 100, T_CANVAS - 100, 0, 0, 0, ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Adrien\\Desktop\\Imagejava\\voiture_exemple.jpg")) , "NORMAL");
    addKeyListener(this);  // rend le canvas rÃ©actif au déplacement du véhicule
  }
    catch(IOException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  // Drawing the rotated image at the required drawing locations

  /* dessin sur le Canvas (mÃ©thode invoquÃ©e automatiquement lorsque nÃ©cessaire) */
  public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    double locationX = vehicule.image.getWidth(null);
    double locationY = vehicule.image.getHeight(null);
    AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(vehicule.a, locationX, locationY);
   // On dessine le fond, puis le véhicule et la piste :
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, T_CANVAS, T_CANVAS);
    try {
    g.drawImage(vehicule.image, tx, null); }
    catch(NullPointerException e) {}
  }


  protected void testerFinPartie() {   
  }


  /* calcule la distance entre deux points */
  static protected double distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
  }

    boolean touche_g = false;
    boolean touche_h = false;
    boolean touche_d = false;
    boolean touche_b = false;

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()) {

        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT :
            touche_g = true;
            vehicule.tourner_g();
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
            touche_d = true;
            vehicule.tourner_d();
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_UP :
            touche_h = true;
            vehicule.avancer();
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN :
            touche_b = true;
            vehicule.reculer();
            break;

        }
    }

    public void deplacer() {
        vehicule.tourner_d();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()) {

            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT :
                touche_g = false;
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
                touche_d = false;
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_UP :
                touche_h = false;
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN :
                touche_b = false;
                break; }
        if (touche_d == false && touche_b == false && touche_h == false && touche_g == false) {
        vehicule.ralentir();    
        }

}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {  }

}
```

### `Vehicle` class

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;





public class Vehicule {
    int x;
    int y;
    int a;
    int dx;
    int da;
    BufferedImage image;
    String mode;

    public Vehicule(int x, int y, int a, int dx, int da, BufferedImage image, String mode) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.a = a;
        this.dx = dx;
        this.da = da;
        this.image = image; 
        mode = "NORMAL";
    }

    public void tourner_g() {
        if (da < (Math.PI/3)) 
        {da += (5*Math.PI/180);}
        a += da;
    }

    public void tourner_d() {
        if (da < (Math.PI/3)) 
        {da += (5*Math.PI/180);}
        a -= da;
    }

    public void avancer() {
        if (dx < 10)
        {dx +=1;}
        x += dx*Math.cos(a);
        y += dx*Math.sin(a);
    }

    public void reculer() {
        if (dx < 10)
        {dx +=1;}
        x -= dx*Math.cos(a);
        y -= dx*Math.sin(a);
    }

    public void ralentir( ) {
        if (dx > 0 || da > 0) {
        dx -= 1;
        da -= 5*Math.PI/180;
        }
    }

    public void deplacer( ) {
        switch(mode) {
        case "NORMAL":

        case "GLISSADE":

        }
    }
}
```

### `JeuKarting` corresponding to the frame

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JeuKarting implements ActionListener {
      JFrame f;        // la fenÃªtre principale du jeu
      JDessin c;  // le canvas ou on dessine la cible et le(s) palets

      public JeuKarting() {
        // crÃ©ation de la fenÃªtre (classe Frame) :
        f = new JFrame("Jeu de Karting...");
        JPanel d = new JPanel ();
        // crÃ©ation du canvas animÃ© pour le jeu  :
        c = new JDessin(50);
        // crÃ©ation de boutons :
        JButton l = new JButton("Lancer une partie");
        JButton p = new JButton("Pause");
        JButton s = new JButton("Sauvegarder");
        // ajout des sous composants Ã  la frame et affichage :
        f.add(c, BorderLayout.NORTH);       
        d.add(s);
        d.add(l);
        d.add(p);
        f.add(d);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        // pour sortir du programme si on ferme la fenÃªtre (par dÃ©faut la fenÃªtre est juste masquÃ©e) :
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        // rend le bouton rÃ©actif au clic :
        s.addActionListener(this);
        p.addActionListener(this);
        l.addActionListener(this);
        // lancement de l'animation :
        c.animer();

      }

      // MÃ©thode invoquÃ©e pour les Ã©vÃ©nements de type "action" : 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      }

      static public void main(String[] args) {
        new JeuKarting();
      }
    }
```

Comment: `catch(NullPointerException e) {}` -- this should **never** be in your code, ever.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i added this catch because there is a null in the method and i had an error message before i actually added it . What would you recommend me ?

Comment: You're simply ignoring a critical problem and sweeping it under the rug which is not how to solve this. Instead find out what is null and then fix the issue that is causing the NPE to be thrown. Use your debugger to help you with this.

Comment: Thank you for the Feedback, the null is the Observer but there is no error now when i remove the try/catch. Would you have any idea of what is the problem with my canvas and my keylistener ? Thank you for giving your time

Comment: The ImageObserver argument should be `this` (the component you’re painting).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I understand why it should this, but this unfortunately did not fix my problem. Thank you anyway for making my code stonger.

Comment: Tip: Add @VGR (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: BTW - *"There are a few problems with my code:"* Then they should be split across a few question threads, so people can find answers to specific questions later. Each question thread should have a [mcve] that is focused on that question. E.G. the problem related to a `KeyListener` requires a `Canvas` in a `JFrame` and neither needs to be to extend that component. There is no need for the (not supplied) `JPanelAnime` class, or multiple `public` classes.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you for the feedback (and the tip !). Sorry about the way it was presented, this is my first asking here and thank's a lot for your corrections.Since I don't know what is the origin of the problem, the code is the same for the two questions so i thought it would be smarter to pack the questions. The JPanelAnime class extends the JFrame class and the JDessin extends JPanelAnime. Everything worked well before i actually decided to use Graphics2D (and added the transformation tx).